# How to implement the logging information in files instead of event viewer using SDL Web 8.5

Tags: event-system, web8.5, logging

Currently we are using event viewer for maintaining the log information.

We want to implement the log information on the file system (using text files). What are the changes are required and how to implement this.

Comment: I see that you've added the `event-system` tag to your question. If it is custom Event System code that you're logging from, then you may want to add that to your questions description. Also, a short code sample of how you are currently logging may help to get answers.

Comment: Welcome to the community, can you **edit** your question and provide a bit more details about from where (Event Handler, Template code, Workflow, Content Delivery etc.) you want to log to a flle?

Comment: Event Handler, Template code, Workflow, Content Delivery  etc logs in  a single file

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll struggle to get Tridion itself to log everything to a file on the CM side, and even more so to the same single file as *all* logs. Maintaining any event system code and configuration that you write could be a pain and you might one day miss some information because you missed out that particular event in the code (or the info was not attributed to an event).

Why not look at using something like [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to consolidate the logs to a single place, e.g. [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) (or maybe a single file if you wish). You could also then add [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) to give you a full "ELK" stack so that you can filter and search over them.